# My Ghost Script command not working with php exec function

Tags: php, cmd, exec, ghostscript

hi please look below command

```
exec("gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=new-file.pdf test.pdf 2>&1",$output);
```

I am able to run this command using **cmd** but not able to run using exec command please help tried a lot. I am using wamp and windows 7.

```
environment variable is set for both php and ghost script
safe mode is off
```

thanks in advance.

**I am getting this output** :-

```
Array ( [0] => 'gswin64c' is not recognized as an internal or external command, [1] => operable program or batch file. )
```

Comment: Your PHP user doesn't have gswin64c.exe available in the $PATH environment variable. Either add the path where Ghostscript is installed to the user's $PATH (this comes up a lot, so just search here for other Qs) or specify the full path spec in your 'exec'. Be aware that Ghostscript is licenced under the AGPL so software as a service usage (which may be what you are doing) is covered under that. If so you either need to open source your own code or seek a commercial licence.

Comment: It seems that php cannot recognize gswin64c as a command. What if you execute `exec("ls")` ?

Comment: @Turtle getting blank Array ( ) when I tried exec("ls",$output); print_r($output); and if i hit exec("git",$output); i am getting array same as we get using cmd that means exec is working.

Comment: @KenS I have already mentioned in the description that I have added environment variable.

Comment: Well, perhaps you made a mistake doing it, got the path wrong, or the wrong user, or something like that. Did you try specifying the exact path in the exec ? Seriously, this question comes up every couple of months and its always the same thing